# How can I make clone to Google Play Notification Style in My Xamarin App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWPob.png)

I want to make Notification in Xamarin that contains an animated download progress picture or video and progress bar and cancellation button (and how can I activate cancellation when it is clicked?) And when it clicked the app opens specific page that contains the downloading object info. How?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom the notification style in your xamarin project. You neet to custom the notification's UI on the each paltform by yourself. There is no a such api can make a cross-platoform notification style in the xamarin.forms.

You can refer to the official document about [creating a custom notification layout in the native android](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification). Then you can custom the notification's style in the xamarin.android.

For the ios, you can refer to the official document about [advanced user notifications in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos).

After this, you can call the native code by the [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to show the notification with the style you want.